# How to make an analytics for my website members page?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a website where members can create their own page. Current I have a script that tracks how many views the member page was viewed. But I would like to display more information like unique visits, return visits etc.

Is there any analytic software that could let me do that?

Comment: What's the problem with using Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to display on each member page some analytics information.

You didn't specify what language you used to build the site.

[Here's a PHP API class](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) to query a Google Analytics account.

Also, check [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) and [this](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?csw=1) for documentation about the API. You can retrieve analytics data / metrics in many ways that the default Analytics reports don't show.

Now you need to think of a way to differentiate between member pages in Analytics (use custom variables in your tracking code, maybe).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with getting in to the Google Analytics API, I suggest you check out some of the solutions on the [Google Analytics Application Gallery](http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/).  I for one work with [embeddedanalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  While we don't have it very well published on our site, we have done a number of CMS type implementations, allowing a single implementation to be used by many different users of the site.  The differentiation could be based on page path or some specific custom variable.  Visit us and contact us directly if you are interested.

(*disclosure - I work with embeddedanalytics*)